# C# Regular Expression always returns FALSE

Tags: c#, regex

```
regexPattern="\w{6}(AAAAA|BBBBB|CCCCC)"
```

I need the strings below to return TRUE. So ANY 6 letters followed by AAAAA or BBBBB or CCCCC:

```
TXCDTLAAAAA000
TXCDTLBBBBB111
TXCDTLCCCCC222
```

but giving the pattern above I always get a FALSE in return. How do I fix this pattern to work right?

So Basically this code is working:

```
    if (Regex.IsMatch("123456BBBBB", @"\w{6}(AAAAA|BBBBB|CCCCC)"))
    {
        //true
    }
```

so I am fixing the code now
Thank you!

Comment: share the code. How are you matching it? in what language?

Comment: Are you enclosing it in delimiters?

Comment: why don't you try `\w{6}(AAAAA|BBBBB|CCCCC)\d+`

Comment: This is C# and d+ didn't make any difference :(

Comment: well, it is matching here: http://regex101.com/r/yJ8bR6/2  .. do check if u've missed out something

Comment: C# requires escaping, or to use verbatim strings. See the answers below.

Comment: Weird, all I am doing is:   returnValue = Regex.IsMatch("AAAAA");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't mention which host language you are using, but the backslash is usually an escape character in double quoted string, so if it is a common language, you may need double backslash

```
 regexPattern="\\w{6}(AAAAA|BBBBB|CCCCC)"
```

Or use another way to express the pattern that doesn't require escape characters. For example, in Python you can prefix the raw string:

```
 regexPattern = r"\w{6}(AAAAA|BBBBB|CCCCC)"
```

Although Python won't treat the \w as an escape sequence anyway, but it will help for others.

With C# use @ (verbatim string) to accomplish it:

```
 var regexPattern = @"\w{6}(AAAAA|BBBBB|CCCCC)";
```

Comment: Python would actually be `pat = re.compile(r"\w{6}((?:AAAAA)|(?:BBBBB)|(?:CCCCC)))`